# Is there a Linux command line tool sequence for converting XML files into a single HTML file?

Tags: html, xml, linux, command-line

I have a bunch of XML files, and I would like to visualize them as tables in an HTML file. I have searched on the net and found [a tutorial on XML->HTML conversion](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12047/How-to-Convert-XML-Files-to-HTML), and a bunch of blogs describing command line tools for HTML/XML/JSON conversion.

Is it possible to use command line tools in Linux to convert a bunch of XML files into a HTML file where each XML file is represented as a [table](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17317/XML-in-Table-View)?

Edit: More background information.

I actually want to analyze the XML output of Google Test, that I'm using to develop geometrical algorithms. Here is how the XML looks like for a single test application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuites tests="27" failures="0" disabled="0" errors="0" timestamp="2014-07-18T10:27:10" time="0.002" name="AllTests">
  <testsuite name="lineSegmentIntersection" tests="3" failures="0" disabled="0" errors="0" time="0">
    <testcase name="halfspaceNoIntersection" status="run" time="0" classname="lineSegmentIntersection" />
    <testcase name="halfspacePointIntersection" status="run" time="0" classname="lineSegmentIntersection" />
    <testcase name="halfspaceRegularIntersection" status="run" time="0" classname="lineSegmentIntersection" />
  </testsuite>
  <testsuite name="polygonIntersection" tests="6" failures="0" disabled="0" errors="0" time="0">
    <testcase name="halfspaceNoIntersection" status="run" time="0" classname="polygonIntersection" />
    <testcase name="halfspacePointFullIntersection" status="run" time="0" classname="polygonIntersection" />
    <testcase name="halfspacePointIntersection" status="run" time="0" classname="polygonIntersection" />
    <testcase name="halfspaceEdgeIntersection" status="run" time="0" classname="polygonIntersection" />
    <testcase name="halfspaceDiagonalIntersection" status="run" time="0" classname="polygonIntersection" />
    <testcase name="halfspaceRegularIntersection" status="run" time="0" classname="polygonIntersection" />
  </testsuite>
  <testsuite name="aabboxIntersection" tests="5" failures="0" disabled="0" errors="0" time="0">
    <testcase name="AABBtrueIntersection" status="run" time="0" classname="aabboxIntersection" />
    <testcase name="AABBpointIntersection" status="run" time="0" classname="aabboxIntersection" />
    <testcase name="AABBedgeIntersection" status="run" time="0" classname="aabboxIntersection" />
    <testcase name="AABBfaceIntersection" status="run" time="0" classname="aabboxIntersection" />
    <testcase name="AABBnoIntersection" status="run" time="0" classname="aabboxIntersection" />
  </testsuite>
  <testsuite name="polyhedronIntersection" tests="11" failures="0" disabled="0" errors="0" time="0.002">
    <testcase name="AABBpointIntersection" status="run" time="0.001" classname="polyhedronIntersection" />
    <testcase name="AABBedgeIntersection" status="run" time="0" classname="polyhedronIntersection" />
    <testcase name="AABBfaceIntersection" status="run" time="0" classname="polyhedronIntersection" />
    <testcase name="AABBtrueIntersection" status="run" time="0" classname="polyhedronIntersection" />
    <testcase name="halfspacePointIntersection" status="run" time="0" classname="polyhedronIntersection" />
    <testcase name="halfspaceEdgeIntersection" status="run" time="0" classname="polyhedronIntersection" />
    <testcase name="halfspaceFaceEmptyIntersection" status="run" time="0" classname="polyhedronIntersection" />
    <testcase name="halfspaceFaceFullIntersection" status="run" time="0" classname="polyhedronIntersection" />
    <testcase name="cubeSpatialDiagonalIntersection" status="run" time="0" classname="polyhedronIntersection" />
    <testcase name="cubeHalvedIntersection" status="run" time="0" classname="polyhedronIntersection" />
    <testcase name="cubeHalvedDiagonally" status="run" time="0.001" classname="polyhedronIntersection" />
  </testsuite>
  <testsuite name="inside" tests="2" failures="0" disabled="0" errors="0" time="0">
    <testcase name="halfspaceTriangle" status="run" time="0" classname="inside" />
    <testcase name="halfspaceTetrahedron" status="run" time="0" classname="inside" />
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

I have dozens of test applications implemented for different geometrical operations, and they all produce such an XML file. As the number of tests grows, I am loosing an overview since I am compiling (generic C++ code) and executing all of them each time I implement a change in the source code that deals with geometry. That's why I would like to pick all of them up and visualize them somehow in tabular form.

Google Test does produce a nice colored output to the command line, but for dozens of applicatins and each of them containing ~10 tests, I need to scroll up to see what has failed.

Answer (score 1):

[XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) is more a family of formats -since it is a [markup language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language)- (e.g. [XHTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML), [Docbook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docbook), ...) than a particular format. You need to know *precisely* which [XML schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xml_schema) is obeyed by your XML files.

You probably want some [XSLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xslt) processor (or perhaps [Xquery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xquery)). See also [SAX parsers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAX_parser) and [Expat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expat_%28XML%29)

Comment: I've edited the question and added more background information. Thanks for the input, I'll check out the XSLT processor.

Comment: What I was hoping for was a chain of command line tools, that I can wrap up in a SHELL script and update the HTML file... But I'll think about using an API also. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As well as XSLT to do the transformation, you might like to look at David Lee's xmlsh which is a shell-like tool for defining XML processing pipelines (there's also XProc and Ant which are widely used for this purpose, but I suggest xmlsh since you appear to be a shell fan).

The XSLT transformation for this input might look something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
   <head>...</head>
   <body><xsl:apply-templates/></body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="testsuites">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr><th>name</th><th>.....</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="testcase">
  <tr>
   <td><xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
   <td><xsl:value-of select="@status"/>
   <td><xsl:value-of select="@time"/>
   <td><xsl:value-of select="@classname"/>
  </tr>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

There are many XSLT processors you can use from the command line. If you choose Saxon, the command would be

```
java -jar saxon9.jar -s:source.xml -xsl:stylesheet.xsl -o:output.html
```